# Defining a Typed Racket structure with a contract

Tags: racket, typed-racket

Is there a way to define alongside a (typed) structure a contract for the entire structure in Typed Racket? In my particular case, I have a structure that takes two lists as fields, and I want to require the lists to be the same length.

I've looked at:

- [`make-struct-type`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/creatingmorestructs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-struct-type%29%29), which allows specification of a "guard" that moderates constructor calls. I could pass a procedure that raises an exception if the lengths don't match, but I don't know what to do with the values returned by `make-struct-type`.
- [`struct/c`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/data-structure-contracts.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fstruct-dc..rkt%29._struct%2Fc%29%29) and the `struct` form of [`contract-out`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/attaching-contracts-to-values.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fbase..rkt%29._contract-out%29%29), both of which produce structure contracts from contracts on individual fields. This seems unhelpful here.

Ideally I would like to bind the contract to the structure immediately (as in `define/contract`), but I'm open to adding the contract when I `provide` the type's procedures. However, I currently provide the recognizer and accessor procedures individually rather than using `struct-out` (so that I can exclude or rename individual procedures), and I'd like to keep that flexibility.

Right now I have something like this:

```
(provide
    (rename-out
        [MyStruct my-struct]
        [MyStruct? my-struct?]
        [MyStruct-foo my-struct-foo]
        [MyStruct-bar my-struct-bar]
    )
)

(struct MyStruct (
    [foo : (Listof Symbol)]
    [bar : (Listof Any)]
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. I'm surprised how difficult it was to do that in Typed Racket. In plain (untyped) Racket its as simple as adding a `#:guard` when making you [`struct`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct%29%29). Unfortunately, the [`struct`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._struct%29%29) form in Typed Racket doesn't support it.

So, to deal with this, I would generate a structure type with a private (to the module) constructor name, and then make your own constructor function that actually does the contract you wanted it to check.

This will end up looking something like:

```
(struct env ([keys : (Listof Symbol)]
             [values : (Listof Any)])
  #:constructor-name internal-env)

(: make-env (-> (Listof Symbol) (Listof Any) env))
(define (make-env k v)
  (unless (= (length k) (length v))
    (raise-arguments-error 'env
                           "env key and value counts don't match"
                           "keys" k
                           "values" v))
  (internal-env k v))
```

Now, when you provide the struct, simply don't provide `internal-env`, but do provide the `make-env` function:

```
(provide (except-out (struct-out env)
                     internal-env)
         make-env)
```

Now, when I construct an env, I get a (dynamic) check to ensure the list lengths match:

```
> (make-env '() '())
#<env>
> (make-env '(a) '(1))
#<env>
> (make-env '(a) '())
env: env key and value counts don't match
  keys: '(a)
  values: '()
```

Comment: -1. I agree that providing a checked constructor is the right thing to do, but -1 because this answer is long, has too many typos, and that "style comment" should be a comment (not part of the answer).

Comment: @Ben Hmm. I agree about the style comment, but not about the typos or length. Seems harsh to me.

Comment: Hmm...would it be better if I moved the style comment to the bottom of the answer? (I didn't put it in a comment because those are supposed to be considered transient sticky notes....at least in theory according to the faq.)

Comment: (But of course, If that's still bad I'd be happy to just remove it altogether. :) )

Comment: Well, according to [Help > Privileges > Comment Everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), comments may be used to leave constructive criticism, which applies here.

Comment: Alright, I took out style comment. FWIW, @Jakob, would you mind if I just cleaned up the style of your original question, or would you prefer it to stay as-is?

Comment: @LeifAndersen I'd like to keep the original style--I disagree with the traditional Scheme style of indentation and parenthesis placement. I've just condensed the code block a bit, however.

Comment: Very well. Works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may find defining and providing the structure definitions with guard functions from Racket, then require/typed-ing and type annotating the structures in Typed Racket a simpler solution than attempting to achieve the same effect purely in Typed Racket.